# How to consume XML/WSDL SOAP in URL using .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, asp.net-core-3.1, sap-basis

I'm currently working on a project regarding pushing and pulling data from SAP in .Net Core. I can create web service in SOAMANAGER in SAP and try to access it in Postman API App.  I can return a value but I'm having trouble when it comes to .Net Core part. I've followed some guides it does not work.

1. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3323584/how-to-consume-a-wcf-soap-service-in-aspnet-core.html
2. https://medium.com/grensesnittet/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb

I am trying yo pull a list of all countries on the SAP as sample

below is my code

HomeController

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<string[]> Get()
{
    CountryName.Z_COUNTRY_TESTING z_COUNTRY_TESTING = new CountryName.Z_COUNTRY_TESTING();
     var data = z_COUNTRY_TESTING.IM_COUNTRY.ToString();

    return Task.Run(Get);
}

public IActionResult GetCountry()
{
    Country country = new Country();
    var data = z_COUNTRY_TESTING.IM_COUNTRY.ToString();
    country = data;

    foreach (var item in country)
    {
        country.CountryName = item.ToString();
    }

    return View(country);
}
```

CountryService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WcfServiceTest
{
    public class CountryService : ICountryService
    {
        public List<string> GetCountryName(string name)
        {
            List<string> listCountries = new List<string>();
            listCountries.Contains(name);
            return listCountries;
        }
    }
}
```

ICountryService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WcfServiceTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICountryService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetCountryName(string name);
    }
}

I hope someone can help me

Thank you.
```